# try to blank out the screen after negative confirmtation

Tags: javascript, window.closed

hi I want to blank out (better was close but `window.cose` doesn't work any more) the screen after a negative confirmation.

I have the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function blankIt ()
{
    document.write ("");
    document.close ();
}

var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('confirmation');
var confirmIt = function (e) {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) e.preventDefault();
};

for (var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
    elems[i].addEventListener('click', confirmIt, false);
}

var confirmIt = function (f) {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) f.preventDefault();
};

for (var i = 1, l = elems.length; i < l; i++) {
    elems[i].addEventListener('click', blankIt, false);
}
</script>
```

I have really no clue.  Maybe someone can point me the right direction

thx in advance

greetz edensan

Answer (score 0):

`document.write()` inserts/appends something to the DOM. It does not alter existing content.

`document.body.innerHTML = '';` should work as expected.

Comment: still no blanc screen on negative confirmtation thats my biggest intention